# How to pass PHP array values to another file using jQuery Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is my code,

```
<?php
$answers = Array( [0] => 13 [1] => 5 [2] => 6 [3] => 11 );
?>

<script>
    function loadData1(val) {
        var dataToSend = {
            'name': val,
            'ans[]': <? php echo $answers; ?>
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: dataToSend,
            url: '<?php echo JURI::ROOT();?>classfiles/sample.php',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#questions').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I want the array values in `sample.php` file, but I don't get any output.

Any useful answers are really appreciated.

Comment: sample.php just contains `<?php
       $answers = Array ( [0] => 13 [1] => 5 [2] => 6 [3] => 11 );
 ?>` ?

Comment: have a look at turning your array into a JSON string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line:

```
var dataToSend = {'name' : val, 'ans[]' : <?php echo $answers; ?> } ;
```

will print:

```
var dataToSend = {'name' : val, 'ans[]' : Array } ;
```

which creates a <del>javascript syntax</del> semantic error (ans = empty string will be posted). Change to:

```
var dataToSend = {'name' : val, 'ans[]' : <?php echo json_encode($answers); ?> } ;
```

which prints:

```
var dataToSend = {'name' : val, 'ans[]' : [13,5,6,11] } ;
```

Comment: suppose key like `ans[]` can make a problem. If I'm not missing something, PHP will parse that like `Array([0] => Array([0] => 13...))`, so simply `ans` should be enough

Comment: @FAngel jQuery will build the string `ans[]=13&ans[]=5&...` which PHP will parse correctly as `$_POST["ans"]=array(13,5,...);`

Comment: @SalmanA Ha! Cool! Sorry, I thought it will build `ans[][]=13&ans[][]=5&...` because array is being passed. But appears that in both cases (when key is `ans` or `ans[]`) it builds a string like `ans[]=13&ans[]=5&...` Will remember this...