# jquery gets data from other page and enter into form fields

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, get

i simply want to get values from test2.php page and fill my form input fieds accordingly on test1.php. please help and advice.

test 2 page

```
$empidx="Design-1012-1000";
$countries = mysqli_query($con,"select country from countries");
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from employee where emprecord='$empidx' ");
$find=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
echo $find['empid'];
```

test 1 page

```
<form id="employees">
    <input type="text" name="empid"><br>
    <input type="text" name="emprecord"><br>
    <input type="text" name="salute"><br>
    <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
    <input type="text" name="mname"><br>
    <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
    <input type="text" name="depart"><br>
    <input type="text" name="desig"><br>
    <input type="text" name="joindate"><br>
    <input type="text" name="leavedate"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

my mysql fields are

```
Id, empid, emprecord, salute, fname, mname, lname, depart, desig, joindate, leavedate
```

Comment: i am still stuck please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can try jQuery AJAX :)
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

or implement test2 page script in test1 page

Answer (score 0):

Fill your form when you generate the page.

```
$input1 = '<input type="text" name="empid" value="'.$find['empid'].'"><br>';
...
```

Or fill your form after the page is loaded with [AJAX and jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

```
$.ajax('test2.php')
    .done(function (data) {
        $('#employees input[name="empid"]').val(data.empid);
        ...
    });
```

Comment: GG i've tried but did'nt work. still my form field empid is empty

Answer (score 0):

Its good if you try this on your own. Here are some links to get you started:

[How to pass PHP array values to another file using jQuery Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498441/how-to-pass-php-array-values-to-another-file-using-jquery-ajax)

[Pass array in jQuery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767279/pass-array-in-jquery-ajax)

[Pass PHP Array via jQuery Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219473/pass-php-array-via-jquery-ajax)

Try it, if these don't help let us know and we will help you.

---

OK, here, i had some time ;-)

test1.php

```
<?php
    $empidx="Design-1012-1000";
$countries = mysqli_query($con,"select country from countries");
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from employee where emprecord='$empidx' ");
$result_array=mysqli_fetch_array($query);

//$result_array = array("1"=>"1","2"=>"2","3"=>"3");
$json = json_encode($result_array);
    print_r($json); 
?>
```

test2.php

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'test1.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#fname').val(data[1]);    
                }
            });
        }); 
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form">
    <input id="fname"/>
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Just configure your result_array  that you are passing. And the script in test2.php is called by default, if thats what you want - then its ok. Otherwise do some click event on it.